# How to determine unique years within date range?

Tags: r, excel, rstudio

I'm trying to determine in what years clients make use of healthcare. The data:

```
Clientnumber   Date start  Date end
1              01-03-2017  31-10-2017
1              01-02-2018  07-08-2018
1              01-11-2018  01-03-2019
1              25-03-2019  01-07-2020
```

For this one client I want to know in what unique years he/she is registered. Thus, the result should be:
`2017, 2018, 2019, 2020` and additonally a count of unique years: `4`.

Is there a way to do this in either Excel or R?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the `YEAR` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, we can get the data in long format, convert to Date and extract year. For each client we can create a comma-separated value of `unique` `Year` and count number of distinct `Year`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -Clientnumber) %>%
  mutate(value = as.Date(value, "%d-%m-%Y"), 
         Year = format(value, "%Y")) %>%
  group_by(Clientnumber) %>%
  summarise(Un_year = toString(unique(Year)), 
            count = n_distinct(Year)) 

# Clientnumber  Un_year                count
#         <int> <chr>                  <int>
#1            1 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020     4
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Clientnumber) %>%
 summarise(Years = map_chr(list(c(Date_start, Date_end)), 
                           ~ toString(unique(substr(., 7, 10)))))

  Clientnumber Years                 
         <int> <chr>                 
1            1 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020
```

If you want also the count, with the addition of `stringr`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Clientnumber) %>%
 summarise(Years = map_chr(list(c(Date_start, Date_end)), 
                           ~ toString(unique(substr(., 7, 10)))),
           n = str_count(Years, ",")+1)

  Clientnumber Years                      n
         <int> <chr>                  <dbl>
1            1 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020     4
```

If the situation is slightly more complicated, meaning you want all years between the first and the last one, even if they are not present in data:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Clientnumber) %>%
 summarise(Years = map_chr(list(c(Date_start, Date_end)), 
                           ~ toString(reduce(range(as.numeric(substr(., 7, 10))), `:`))),
           n = str_count(Years, ",")+1)
```